# Ajax call works on one page but doesn't execute php (url) when called from another

Tags: php, ajax

I am developing a simple blogging site that I wish to include a 'like post' feature. I've included an ajax call so I can post to the db without reloading the page. This works on my index page, however, when making the same ajax call from another page (user profile page) it doesn't execute the php file, and instead just returns the page html.

index.php & profile.php snippet

```
<form id="likeBlog">
   <button type="button" onclick="likeBlog(param1, param2);">
</form>
```

main.js (within the likeBlog() function)

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'ajax.php',
   data: data,
   success: function(response){
      alert(response);
      // success code
   },
   processData: true
});
```

Comment: You seem to load `ajax.php` relatively from the current URL. That means that if you are on the index page `/`, it will load `/ajax.php` (from the root). If you are in some URL hierarchy, like `/foo`, then it will try and load `/foo/ajax.php`, where it probably isn't. This is just a guess but try and add `url: '/ajax.php'` (prefixed with a slash) and see if that works better.

Comment: If it makes no difference, then check the browsers console for errors, and check if the request is made (under the Network tab in the browsers development tools), what it sends and what it response with.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you've hit the nail on the head right away! Prefixing ajax.php with `/` has done the trick, thank you! As a side note, this is my first question I have posted on here, so is there a way to mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: @AlonEitan I'd already fixed the issue with Magnus' response otherwise yes, your link would have solved my problem also, so thank you